# How can I replace codes of a variable (food Ingredient) with value (calorie) from another dataset?

Tags: stata

I have a Stata dataset which has six variables with consumed food ingredient codes and their weight in grams. I have another distinct dataset which has food ingredient codes and consecutive calorie per 100 g. I need to replace codes with calorie to calculate total calorie consumption.

How can I do that? (by replacing or generating new variable)

My first (master) dataset is

```
clear 
input double hhid int(Ingredient_1_code Ingredient_1_weight Ingredient_2_code incredient_2_weight Ingredient_3_code ingredient_3_weight Ingredient_4_code Ingredient_4_weight Ingredient_5_code Ingredient_5_weight Ingredient_6_code Ingredient_6_weight)
   1  269    8 266  46    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1  315   19   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1  316    9   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1 2522    3   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1    1 1570   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1    1  530   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1   61  262  64  23   57  17   31   8 2522   5    .  .
   1  130   78  64  23   57  17 2521   2   31  15  248  1
   1  228  578  64 138   57  37  248   3 2521  14   31 35
   2  142  328   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   2  272   78   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   2    1  602   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   2   51  344  61 212  246   2   64  50   65  11 2522 10
   2  176  402  44 348   61 163   57  17  248   2   64 71
 3.1    1 1219   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
 3.1    1  410   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
 3.1   54  130  52  60   61  32   51  23   21  17   57  4
 3.1   44   78 130  44   57   3  248   4   31  49 2522  6
 3.1  231  116 904 119   61 220   57  22  248   3  254  6
 3.2  156  396   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
 3.2  272   78   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
end
```

My second dataset with food ingredient codes and calorie per 100 g is

```
clear
input str39 Ingredient int(Ingredient_codes Calorie_per_100gm)
"Parboiled rice (coarse)"        1 344
"Non-parboiled rice (coarse)"    2 344
"Fine rice"                      3 344
"Rice flour"                     4 366
"Suji (cream of wheat/barley)"   5 364
"Wheat"                          6 347
"Atta"                           7 334
"Maida (wheat flour w/o bran)"   8 346
"Semai/noodles"                  9 347
"Chaatu"                        10 324
"Chira (flattened rice)"        11 356
"Muri/Khoi (puffed rice)"       12 361
"Barley"                        13 324
"Sagu"                          14 346
"Corn"                          15 355
"Cerelac"                       16 418
"Lentil"                        21 317
"Chick pea"                     22 327
"Anchor daal"                   23 375
"Black gram"                    24 317
"Khesari"                       25 352
"Mung"                          26 161
end
```

I want to get calories per 100 g in master dataset in according to ingredients.

Comment: You need to `reshape long` your first dataset and then `merge m:1` on a code variable.

Comment: @NickCox Can't reshape because  hhid doesn't uniquely identify the observations as same household has multiple ingredients. Can you please provide some more way ?

Comment: Not so.  `collapse` whatever you don't care about keeping separate and then use another variable to identify "columns" to map to observations.  See the help and also https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/problems-with-reshape/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment Nick made about it is better to first make this data long. Read why that is a much better practice here: https://worldbank.github.io/dime-data-handbook/processing.html#making-data-tidy

However, it can be done in the current un-tidy wide format if you for some reason must keep your data like that. The code below shows how that can be done.

```
clear
input str39 Ingredient int(Ingredient_codes Calorie_per_100gm)
"Parboiled rice (coarse)"        1 344
"Non-parboiled rice (coarse)"    2 344
"Fine rice"                      3 344
"Rice flour"                     4 366
"Suji (cream of wheat/barley)"   5 364
"Wheat"                          6 347
"Atta"                           7 334
"Maida (wheat flour w/o bran)"   8 346
"Semai/noodles"                  9 347
"Chaatu"                        10 324
"Chira (flattened rice)"        11 356
"Muri/Khoi (puffed rice)"       12 361
"Barley"                        13 324
"Sagu"                          14 346
"Corn"                          15 355
"Cerelac"                       16 418
"Lentil"                        21 317
"Chick pea"                     22 327
"Anchor daal"                   23 375
"Black gram"                    24 317
"Khesari"                       25 352
"Mung"                          26 161
end 

drop Ingredient

tempfile code_calories
save `code_calories'


clear 
input double hhid int(Ingredient_1_code Ingredient_1_weight Ingredient_2_code incredient_2_weight Ingredient_3_code ingredient_3_weight Ingredient_4_code Ingredient_4_weight Ingredient_5_code Ingredient_5_weight Ingredient_6_code Ingredient_6_weight)
   1  269    8 266  46    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1  315   19   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1  316    9   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1 2522    3   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1    1 1570   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1    1  530   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   1   61  262  64  23   57  17   31   8 2522   5    .  .
   1  130   78  64  23   57  17 2521   2   31  15  248  1
   1  228  578  64 138   57  37  248   3 2521  14   31 35
   2  142  328   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   2  272   78   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   2    1  602   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
   2   51  344  61 212  246   2   64  50   65  11 2522 10
   2  176  402  44 348   61 163   57  17  248   2   64 71
 3.1    1 1219   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
 3.1    1  410   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
 3.1   54  130  52  60   61  32   51  23   21  17   57  4
 3.1   44   78 130  44   57   3  248   4   31  49 2522  6
 3.1  231  116 904 119   61 220   57  22  248   3  254  6
 3.2  156  396   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
 3.2  272   78   .   .    .   .    .   .    .   .    .  .
end 

*Standardize varname
rename incredient_2_weight Ingredient_2_weight
rename ingredient_3_weight Ingredient_3_weight

*Loop over all variables
forvalues var_num = 1/6 {
    
    *Rename to match name in code_calories dataset
    rename Ingredient_`var_num'_code Ingredient_codes
    
    *Merge calories for this ingridient
    merge m:1 Ingredient_codes using `code_calories', keep(master matched) nogen
    
    *Calculate number of calories for this ingredient
    gen   Calories_`var_num' = Calorie_per_100gm * Ingredient_`var_num'_weight
    
    *Order new variables and restore names of variables
    order Calorie_per_100gm Calories_`var_num', after(Ingredient_`var_num'_weight)
    rename Ingredient_codes Ingredient_`var_num'_code 
    rename Calorie_per_100gm Calorie_per_100gm_`var_num'    
}

*Summarize calories across all ingredients
egen total_calories = rowtotal(Calories_?)
```

Comment: the line -rename Ingredient_`var_num'_code Ingredient_codes not working because after first rename, it shows already has variable- Ingredient_codes. Any suggestion?

Comment: I re-ran the code and do not get any error. Do you get that error when you run the exact code in my answer or when you apply it to your full data?

Comment: yes, it gives error message as "variable Ingredient_codes already defined"

Comment: I have tested this on multiple systems, and I have had other people test my code, but in no case is the error you describing reproduced. What version of Stata are you using? Are you running my code block by itself, with no modifications, and not integrated with other code of yours?

Comment: It's STATA 16.  I tried both but somehow didn't work.

Comment: This is very weird as I tested on multiple systems and it is only on your system that it does not work